# How do I correctly locate a div within a list when making a horizontal nav bar with HTML/CSS?

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a horizontal nav bar in CSS and would like the icons to be placed in the following order from left to rigiht: +Matthew, Gmail, Images, 3x3 Square Block, Alarm Clock, Google Plus, Smiley Face. The problem is that the 3x3 Square Block always locates to the far right and does not fit in with the rest of the list. The block was created using a separate div and blocks with CSS. How do I make it so that I can place it as the fourth item from the left? Also, I am struggling to properly align my Google Plus icon with the rest of the list items. Whenever I try to set a seperate padding for the icon, it moves all of the icons down as well. Here's my code:

```
<ul>
  <li><a class ="headerLink matthew" href="#home">+Matthew</a></li>
  <li><a class ="headerLink gmail" href="#news">Gmail</a></li>
  <li><a class ="headerLink images" href="#contact">Images</a></li>
  <li>
    <div id="googleApps"> <a href="https://www.google.com/drive/">
        <div class ="googleDocs"></div>
    <div class ="square"></div>
    <div class ="square"></div>
    <div class ="square"></div>
    <div class ="square"></div>
    <div class ="square"></div>
    <div class ="square"></div>
    <div class ="square"></div>
    <div class ="square"></div>
    <div class ="square"></div>
    </div>      
    <li> <a class="headerLink alarm" href="https://www.nba.com">&#9742;</a>       </li>

    <li><a href="https://plus.google.com/"><img class="headerLink googlePlus"      src="http://www.siam.org/publicawareness/images/Google-plus-icon.png"></a>

    <li><a class="headerLink profPic" href="https://plus.google.com/+MatthewThrasher/posts">&#9786;</a></li>

</ul>


#googleApps {
height:20px;
width:20px;
position:relative;
float:right;
}
#googleApps:hover .square {
background-color:black;
}
.headerLink {
font-size: 12px;
color:#989898;
text-decoration:none;
font-family:"Arial", arial, sans-serif;
padding-left:30px;
}
.matthew:hover, .gmail:hover, .images:hover {
text-decoration:underline;
}
.square {
background-color:#737373;
float:left;
position: relative;
width: 30%;
padding-bottom: 30.66%;
margin:1.66%;
}
.square:hover {
background-color:black;
}
.driveLink {
width:20px;
height:20px;
background-color:white;
color:white;
/*Important:*/
position:relative;
}
.alarm {
font-size: 25px;
}
.googlePlus {
height: 30px;
width: 30px;
}
.profPic {
font-size: 30px;
}
```

Comment: I'm struggling to understand what you're trying to do. Could you post the CSS targeting the `<ul>` as well as some more details on how it should look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you have more CSS in your document but you're missing a bit of CSS to actually make your menu horizontal.

> You can make it horizontal by adding to your CSS:

```
li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

> Extra properties in your CSS was pushing your squares to the side.

Remove `float:right` and it should align properly.

> Pretty much everything else was caused by missing closing tags.

I fixed up the code and made comments where they were missing: http://jsbin.com/letuwahuqe/1/edit?html,css,output

Just some tips as you continue coding - you should really pay attention to your formatting and syntax.  Not sure how you're working on your stuff but the code you copy and pasted here has a lot of inconsistent spacing in both HTML and CSS.  This makes it really hard to catch mistakes like missing tags and especially difficult for other people looking at your code to understand.

I recommend using something like [Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/) (it's free!) which will make your life a lot easier!

Comment: Thanks a lot! I appreciate the response. The formatting was pretty sloppy. I'm new to this and will definitely check out Sublime Text. Thanks again for taking the time to answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by adding the following CSS to your code:

```
li {
display: inline;
}
```

I think this will do it!

I also resized your icon:

```
<a href="https://plus.google.com/"><img class="headerLink googlePlus"      src="http://www.siam.org/publicawareness/images/Google-plus-icon.png" style="height: 20px; width: 20px;"></a>
```